# How would I write that doesn't use DictReader but gets the same result as if DictReader was used?

Tags: python, file, csv

Essentially, let's say my CSV file is this:

```
name,job,age
Michael,Engineer,35
Katie,Doctor,52
Johnny,Physicist,42
```

Then I would want to return this:

```
{'name':'Michael','job':'Engineer','age':'35'}
{'name':'Katie','job':'Doctor','age':'52'}
{'name':'Johnny','job':'Physicist','age':'42'}
```

Of course, this is simple to do using a DictReader, but I want to do this the long way.How would I go about doing this without using DictReader?

Comment: I mean, what exactly do you want to use? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Don't really know where to start. And I'll add, I don't want to use pandas either. No libraries (besides csv obviously).

Comment: **Start** by asking yourself, what information would you need from the file in order to turn each line of it into a dictionary with the proper keys — then try to implement that.

Comment: Ok, then something like `header = next(reader); results = [dict(zip(header, row)) for row in reader]`

Comment: What does the zip function exactly do? And what would the alternative method to using it? My thought process was to loop through the header and then loop through the rest of the lines of the file, creating a new dict every loop and updating it as I should. I'm just running into a bunch of indices errors and stuff like that.

Comment: Sounds like you have tried to code it.  *Show the code in your question*!

Comment: I've updated the post so show you what I currently have

Answer (score 0):

You can do it farily easily by using the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to create a sequence of (key, value) pairs that can be passed to the `dict()` constructor to create one for each row of data:

```
from pprint import pprint

def readFile(reader):
    list1 = []
    header = next(reader).strip().split(',')
    for line in reader:
        row = dict(zip(header, line.strip().split(',')))
        list1.append(row)
    return list1

with open('people.csv') as file:
    list1 = readFile(file)
    pprint(list1, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'Michael', 'job': 'Engineer', 'age': '35'},
 {'name': 'Katie', 'job': 'Doctor', 'age': '52'},
 {'name': 'Johnny', 'job': 'Physicist', 'age': '42'}]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to [read the csv file as a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and then [convert to dictionary](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html).

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data_in_dataframe = pd.read_csv('csv_file_name.csv')

data_in_dictionary = data_in_dataframe.to_dict()

# Now print the entries    
for entry in data_in_dictionary.keys():
    print(data_in_dictionary[entry])
```